# Using 'as' and 'will'

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure, as

I was wondering about the usage of 'as' and 'will'.

> 'As she will go to the cinema, I will go too.'
>   'As the waiter will wipe the table clean, I will sit at it.'

I know about the rule that applies to 'if' and 'will', is the same true for 'as' and 'will'? I tried looking it up in books, but couldn't find the rule.

Answer (score 1):

The word "as" in your examples is a conjunction. The word ["as"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/as#Conjunction) has several meanings as a conjunction, but the meaning that is most likely in the examples you give is "because". Neither sentence reads like native English, but the first means: "I will go to the cinema because she will go to the cinema", and the second means "I will sit at the table because the waiter will clean it". I would choose to use "because" instead of "as" in these sentences, to avoid confusion with other meanings of "as".

Compare the sentence "I will sit at the table as the waiter cleans it". The meaning of "as" here is "while". By using the simple present tense, the sentence implies that the act of sitting will start and finish during the cleaning of the table.

Understanding which meaning of "as" is intended depends on the context of the question, and there are sentences which are ambiguous: "I will sit at the table as the waiter is cleaning it" is ambiguous. In this example "as" could mean either "while" or "because". A skilled speaker will avoid such ambiguity.

So don't think about rules, think about meaning. What meaning is most likely in context? And don't use "as" when "while" or "because" would be clearer.